# Support for Team Explorer in VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Are there plans to support Team Explorer Everywhere with the Mac version of VS Code or similar hook to TFS?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding after listingen to this webcast from Build https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-680 that the team is focusing on a good editor not an IDE. For me is the Team Explorer Everywhere more on the IDE side. [This is my personal opinion, I don't have any special insight into the project]

Hooks: Visual Studio Online have serveral service hooks that you maybe can leverage? https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/integrate/integrating-with-service-hooks-vs

Comment: Right, I would not assume this to be another view in the editor, but one could argue that we should support TFS SCM from the changes view that currently is used for git.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, the changes view for git is where I was going with the TFS inquiry.  Right now, our dev teams are leveraging git for front-end development but traditionally we have been a MS shop and have a large investment in those tools like TFS, so we have code in both worlds.  I can understand the desire to keep the editor lightweight and not build a VS IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not, but you can propose this on our [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code).

Comment: Apologies, I should have searched there first.  There is already a post for adding TFS support.